# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@val4'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters, sql-server-2012

Hey all I am not sure why I am getting this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@val4'

When I try running this code in C#:

```
SELECT * FROM tT WHERE active = @val1 AND (ApDate BETWEEN @val2 AND @val3) AND @val4
```

The data for the query above is:

```
@val1 = 1
@val2 = 9/30/2016 12:00:00 AM
@val3 = 9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM
@val4 =  (RequestID = 0  OR RequestID =469 OR RequestID =471 OR RequestID =472 OR 
          RequestID =473 OR RequestID =474 OR RequestID =494 OR 
          RequestID =496 OR RequestID =497)
```

So putting that altogether it looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tT 
WHERE active = 1 
AND (ApDate BETWEEN '9/30/2016 12:00:00 AM' AND '9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM') 
AND (RequestID = 0  OR RequestID =469 OR RequestID =471 OR RequestID =472 OR 
     RequestID =473 OR RequestID =474 OR RequestID =494 OR 
     RequestID =496 OR RequestID =497)
```

However, when I run that same query within the Server Management Studio it runs just fine...

And I'm just using this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", Value_here);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", Value_here);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", Value_here);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", Value_here);
```

As the means to add the 4 parameters to the query.

**NOTE** Not a dup of currently same named questions as they do not make since to the question at hand.

Comment: @DavidG it is being compared.. its being compared to **RequestID**

Comment: Sorry, misread. But it seems like you are trying to pass in raw SQL as a parameter, is that right? Can you show how you are doing that?

Comment: So you have the answer now, but also I recommend http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: You can't pass logic as a parameter. Parameters are values, not statements. And since you are using ad hoc queries you should be explicit with your datatypes. They don't always get interpreted correctly. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @SeanLange I beat you to the link :)

Comment: @DavidG I noticed that when i posted mine. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Any idea if `AddWithValue` is in .Net Core? Not had a look yet, but I hope it's been burned!

Comment: @DavidG not sure. Haven't looked either.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put SQL Statements into parameters inside an SQL statement.

The SQL Server will not recognize the SQL inside the parameter as it is expecting a value.

Comment: So I just need to pass it as a normal string then?

Comment: I would strongly caution you against building up a string like that as it is prone to sql injection.

Comment: @SeanLange Well, only if the user can somehow manipulate the string

Comment: @Istanfin Which is very easy to do in many situations, that's why SQL injection is still the biggest security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx) and a stored procedure to do this.

First, you would need to create a table type to use with the procedure:

```
create type dbo.Id_udt as table (Id int not null);
go
```

Then, create a procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.get_requests (
    @IsActive bit
  , @FromDate datetime
  , @ThruDate datetime
  , @Ids as dbo.Id_udt readonly
) as 
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;

  select * 
  from t 
    inner join @Ids as i
      on t.RequestID = i.RequestID
  where t.active = @IsActive
    and t.apdate between @FromDate and @ThruDate

end;
go
```

Then, assemble and pass the list of `RequestIDs` to the stored procedure using a `DataTable` added as a `SqlParameter` using `SqlDbType.Structured`.

Table Valued Parameter Reference:

- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Table Value Parameter Use With C# - Jignesh Trivedi](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-value-parameter-use-with-C-Sharp/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- [Maximizing Performance with Table-Valued Parameters - Dan Guzman](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)
- [Maximizing throughput with tvp - sqlcat](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/23/maximizing-throughput-with-tvp/)
- [How to use TVPs with Entity Framework 4.1 and CodeFirst](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures)